# Feature request : SO should automatically delete Chat-GPT answers

Tags: support

I tried to copy an answer from Chat-GPT and paste it in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120888

SO was not able to detect it as a Chat-GPT answer. Why this feature is not implemented yet?

Comment: That answer was not auto-deleted. It was manually deleted by a moderator for not answering the question.

Comment: I don't think this question is mistakenly asking 'why was my answer auto-deleted' - I *think* AmruthA is asking why there is no mechanism on this site to help us detect ChatGPT-generated answers and whether there are any plans in future to add something. However, I appreciate the mismatch between the title and the question body here means it's all a little unclear as it stands... AmruthA: Could you reword your question a little to make your main purpose clearer, please? Thanks!

Comment: How can you detect that something is written by ChatGPT? I thought this is a hard open research problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChatGPT answers are not delete-worthy simply because they are ChatGPT answers.

> With due consideration, we've decided no network-wide, general policy regarding banning ChatGPT, or other AI generated content, is necessary or helpful at this time.
>       <sup>— [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002)</sup>

Note this specifically does *not* mean that they are ok; they're very likely not:

- If the answer does not actually address the question, it is Not An Answer and can be deleted as such.
- If the answer is altogether wrong and does not provide an intelligible reasoning for the solution it suggests, it can be flagged so it lands in the Low Quality Posts review queue, and likely deleted from there.
- If the true source of the answer is not disclosed, this is actual plagiarism which is in and of itself grounds for deletion.

Anecdotally, it's much more common than not that at least two of these, if not all three, are true of ChatGPT answers.

In other words, ChatGPT answers are pretty much invariably delete-worthy just because of what they say, without even having to take into account that they're ChatGPT answers.  The same moderation activities our community engages in to deal with poor answers are equally applied to generated answers, and at least for now there seems to be no particular urgency for StackExchange to build a detector to automatically do anything with such answers.

**IF** the quality of generated output from ChatGPT and similar were to markedly improve, such that we saw actually relevant ChatGPT answers that were properly attributed as such and which managed to correctly answer the question, with a cogent and pertinent line of reasoning to explain why the posited answer is the correct one, then ... we've landed in https://xkcd.com/810/ territory.

Until then —
a bad answer is a bad answer, regardless of its origin.  ChatGPT, being a language model and not a reasoning engine, isn't *solving* puzzles, it's guessing what text it can spit out that might be a reasonable response to the input prompt. It's very likely nowhere near correct, its line of "reasoning" is almost certainly nonsensical and often self-contradictory, and in short, the whole effort amounts to a bad answer.

If you see such an answer, feel free to downvote, and flag/delete-vote for not being an answer.
If you're tempted to post such an answer, please don't. You're not fooling anyone and it's just adding noise to the site. Even doing this "for science" isn't useful; SE's stance on the issue is already given in the post I linked at the top, so it shouldn't be surprising that such answers are not automatically deleted.

Given that these answers are already typically delete-worthy irrespective of being ChatGPT originated, I don't think it's necessary at this time to create additional policy to specifically ban or delete them *just* for being ChatGPT originated. The other reasons suffice, and someone posting a ChatGPT answer can very likely expect it to be deleted in short order for one of those reasons.

Comment: Rule of thumb: ChatGBT only pretends to know its answers, so should only be used when pretending is the point.